# Avoiding to repeatedly test for nulls on the same properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have many entities that have the `IsActive` property. For internal reasons, I need all those fields to be nullable. On the other hand, for every entity I may have to do a double test in tens of places in the application:

(null are treated as true)

```
if (language.IsActive == null || language.IsActive.value)
```

If I create a method like

```
class Language
{
   public bool IsActiveLanguage()
   {
       return language.IsActive == null || language.IsActive.value;
   }
}
```

It still won't hide the property (at least from inside the class) so it's error prone.

I tried to find a way to override, but of course I can't change the return type to plain `bool`.

What would you do to avoid redundancy in this case?

Comment: So in your case null is equivalent to *true*, not false? That's slightly unusual.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of "as long as it's not false, it's true". I agree that this is probably not a best practice!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `GetValueOrDefault` method, specifying the value to be used in place of `null`:

```
public bool IsActiveLanguage()
{
    return language.IsActive.GetValueOrDefault(true);
}
```

**NOTE:**

Whether to use the CLR method (`GetValueOrDefault`) or the language operator (`??` in C#, `If(,)` in VB) makes no difference to the result, it's merely a question of code consistency. Personally, I use the language operator in places where I want to treat nullable value types and strings in the same way, but the CLR method in places where I want to emphasise exactly what is happening with the nullable value.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [the null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), so your example would become:

```
return language.IsActive ?? true;
```

Answer (score 3):

If your property is `Nullable<>` and a `null` value means `true`, you could use this instead of an explicit null check:

```
language.IsActive.GetValueOrDefault(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

good answers were given, i would maybe do a

```
public static bool IsActive(bool? toCheck)
{
   return toCheck.GetValueOrDefault(true);
}
```

on some static helper class.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just hide this implementation detail in the getter:

```
private bool? _IsActive;
public bool IsActive { get { return !_IsActive.HasValue ||_IsActive; } }
```

EDIT: After realizing the properties are generated and can't be modified

You could declare a new type, called ThreeValBool, which is essentially a bool?, and add an implicit cast from it to bool, like so:

```
struct ThreeValBool
{
    private bool? _value;

    public static implicit operator bool(ThreeValBool tvb)
    {
        return !tvb._value.HasValue || tvb.value;
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to add a way to set the value...

Make your properties of that type (hopefully the designer will let you do that).

Comment: Because the implementation is in a .designer.cs file. Otherwise yes, this would be a good solution!

Comment: Well, can you make the IsActive generated property private? If so, you can add your IsReallyActive property that does the same.

Comment: Seems a bit bulky to have this all over the place. If this were the route, I'd give AOP a shot to make it a little shorter. Put an attribute over IsActive to override the return value. Also giving the ability to reuse it over other weird booleans.

Comment: OK, I have another idea. Time for a second answer. I'll edit.